# Migrate comments to Disqus

Tags: comments, migration, disqus

Is there a way to migrate all comments on my blog over to Disqus somehow? Thinking about using Disqus rather than the regular WordPress comments, but I don't want to lose the comments that are already written.

Comment: That's a part of the activation process. Install the plugin, active and follow the steps, you will eventually hit a point where it asks if you want to export blog comments.

Comment: Ah, cool. Will probably try that out then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Disqus export comments]

During the process of installing the [Disqus Comment System plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/disqus-comment-system/) on WordPress, it actually allows you to export your comments to Disqus, as shown in the screenshot above.

And they've quite a helpful documentation as well:

- [Install Disqus on WordPress (self-hosted)](http://disqus.com/admin/wordpress/)
- [Exporting comments from WordPress to Disqus](http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/466255-exporting-comments-from-wordpress-to-disqus)

Not to mention the numerous 'how-to' videos on YouTube. :)